Can GeoNodes interact with geometry that has Material Displacement?
I'm glad Displacement works as a shader so I can use shader nodes to control its properties, (as opposed to displacement modifier which can only use one height map,) but don't I lose the ability do use geometry nodes features such as ray-cast or find nearest point? Is it possible there's a work-around where geometry-nodes accesses material properties?

I don't think it is possible. I think displacement is computed at the very end of the pipeline, at rendering, when the geometry has been send to the GPU to be rendered. In the same way you can't sample the rendered material to use to change geometry/shaders with Cycles.
